# Customize CSS of default page in SAP Business Objects

Tags: css, business-objects

I would like to be able to change the colors of a few items, and add a `<hr/>` to the bottom of the default page.  Looking to distinguish between DEV / QA / PROD environments with subtle color changes.  I guess I am looking for the master/default index.html/jsp page or the main CSS file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to SAP, these objects are wrapped within a jar file, inaccessible to clients.  So, there's your answer to that one.